# v4l2loopback: Virtual camera exists, but doesn't show up in Zoom, and doesn't work in Cheese

Tags: ubuntu, v4l, v4l2loopback, obs-studio

I have successfully set up the virtual camera in OBS:

```
sudo apt install obs-studio v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo usermod -aG video myuser
```

The following versions are installed:

```
v4l2loopback-dkms 0.12.5-1
obs-studio 26.1.2+dfsg1-1~ubuntu20.10.1~ppa1
Kernel: 5.11.0-11-lowlatency
```

After a reboot, the virtual camera button and settings are showing up in OBS, and clicking the start button creates the following CLI output:

```
info: Virtual camera started
info: ==== Virtual Camera Start ==========================================
```

It also seems to work according to v4l2-ctl:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
OBS Virtual Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video6

USB 2.0 Camera: USB 2.0 Camera (usb-0000:00:14.0-4.2):
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/media2

Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:14.0-6):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1
```

After changing the refresh rate in `OBS -> Settings -> Video` to **30 fps**, the virtual camera also shows up in **Cheese**, but selecting it there, Cheese can not use it and displays an error `There was an error playing video from the webcam`. Cheese does not create any CLI output.

In **Zoom**, the virtual camera does not show up in the selection menu at all.

I also experimented with different **color format** settings in `OBS -> Settings -> Advanced`, but to no avail, it doesn't affect the outcome.

Any idea what could be a reason?

[Update:] The virtual camera works when using VLC. This to me indicates a problem with the output format. However, I have tested all possible output resolutions, frame rates, and color formats offered by OBS, and none work with Cheese or Zoom.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the virtual camera works in Zoom, but only using the Ubuntu app, and not in Chrome. So at least for Zoom, that's a decent method/workaround, though no such luck on Webex, as they don't have a Linux app (one is [reportedly in the works though](https://blog.webex.com/team-collaboration/webex-community-members-bring-linux-support-for-webex-to-life/)).

Also can't explain why Cheese doesn't work that way. So I don't have a full solution yet, but at least *something* works...